# Stochastic integral under stopping

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $\nu^+$ (resp. $\nu$) be the set of all real valued processes $A$ that are càdlàg, adapted with $A_0=0$ and whose each path is non-decreasing (resp. has finite variation over each finite interval $[0,t]$).

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the set of all stochastic processes $A\in\nu$ which satisfy $$E[\text{Var}(A)_\infty]<\infty$$ 
and $\mathcal{A}^+$ the set of all processes $A\in\nu^+$ which satisfy $$E[A_\infty]<\infty$$ where $\text{Var}(.)$ is the variation of a stochastic process. 
Furthermore we know that $$\mathcal{A}_{loc}=\mathcal{A}^+_{loc}\ominus\mathcal{A}^+_{loc}$$.

Let $A\in\mathcal{A}_{\text{ loc}}$. Then there is a sequence of stopping times $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $A^{T_n}\in\mathcal{A}$ and processes $B,C\in\mathcal{A}^+_{loc}$, uniquely determined up to evanescent, s.t. there are localizing sequences of stopping times $(T_n')_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(T_n'')_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $$A^{T_n}=B^{T_n'}-C^{T_n''}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now let $H$ be a predictable process and $H\cdot A\in\mathcal{A}_{\text{ loc}}$. Then $H^+\cdot (B^{T_n'})$ is clearly increasing and since $(B^{T_n'})\in\nu^+$, $H^+\cdot (B^{T_n'})\in\nu^+$.

But my aim is to show $H^+\cdot B\in\mathcal{A}_{loc}^+$. So the question is if $H^+\cdot (B^{T_n'})=(H^+\cdot B)^{T_n'}$ holds and how to proof that $E[(H^+\cdot B)^{T_n'''}_\infty]=E[(H^+\cdot B)_{T_n'''}]<\infty$ for an appropriate stopping time $T_n'''$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following easy to verify equalities
\begin{gather}
(B^T)_t=B_{T\wedge t}=(1_{ \,{[\!\![}\, 0,T\; ]\!\!]}\cdot B)_t.\\
(H\cdot B)^T=(H 1_{\,{[\!\![}\, 0,T\;]\!\!]})\cdot B= (H 1_{\,{[\!\![}\, 0,T\;]\!\!]})\cdot B^T=H\cdot (B^T).\\
\text{Var}(H\cdot A)= |H|\cdot \text{Var}(A). \tag{1}
\end{gather}
From (1), if $(H\cdot A)\in\mathcal{A}_{\text{loc}}$, then there exists a sequence $\{T_n, n\ge 1\}$ of stopping times such that, $T_n\uparrow +\infty$ and $(|H|\cdot \text{Var}(A))^{T_n}\in \mathcal{A}^+$. Since 
$H^+\cdot B\le |H|\cdot \text{Var}(A)$, then $(H^+\cdot B)^{T_n}\in \mathcal{A}^+$ too.

Comment: This explains why $H^+\cdot B\in\nu^+$, thanks. But how can i show that $E[(H^+\cdot B)_\infty^{T_n'}]<\infty$? My idea is to say $(H^+\cdot B)_\infty^{T_n'}<\infty$ a.s. and this implies $E[(H^+\cdot B)_{\infty}^{T_n'}]<\infty$?

Comment: @peer, I add some facts to answer your question. If you have any question about it, please don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Ok, since $H\cdot A\in\mathcal{A}_{\text{loc}}$, we have in particular $H\cdot A\in\nu_{\text{loc}}=\nu$ which means that $H^+\cdot Var(A) - H^-\cdot Var(A)=\left|H\right|\cdot Var(A)=Var(H\cdot A)<\infty$. But i am not sure how this helps in prooving that $E[(H^+\cdot B)_{T_{n'}}]<\infty$?

Comment: @peer, Thank you for your replication, I add a sentence in the last place to reply your question.

Comment: Now, i think i get it. $H\cdot A\in\mathcal{A}_{\text{loc}}$ means in particular that we can find a sequence of stopping times $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $E[\text{Var}((H\cdot A)^{T_n})_\infty]<\infty$. Furthermore $E[\text{Var}((H\cdot A)^{T_n})_\infty]=E[\text{Var}((H\cdot A))_{T_n}]=E[(\left|H\right|\cdot Var(A))_{T_n}]$ and $H^+\cdot B\le |H|\cdot \text{Var}(A)$ yields that $E[(H^+\cdot B)^{T_n}_\infty]<\infty$. Is this correct?

Comment: @peer, your deduction is correct.